# angular2 texfield value sync up in all browser

Tags: javascript, angular, lite-server

I take a little surprise today working with angular 2, i'm developing a single page form to capture some data, and i discover that the value enter in my texfield using google chrome is sync up with my other browser mozilla firefox.
Anybody have some idea why happen this. this not look like angular function.
i'm running in developer mode
[here my package.json file](https://github.com/manunoly/gestionProyectos/blob/master/package.json)

reading more about lite-server with npm i suspect that it could be the reason but i'm not sure.

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is browser-sync which is used by lite-server.

Comment: thanks for the answer. that confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of lite-server browsersync 
to remove this you can use http-server(npm install -g http-server)